# What driver should I use on ubuntu 22.04 for RTX 3060?

Tags: 22.04, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I have set my PC on dual boot: windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04. I obsverved that my PC got really hot when using ubuntu. I suspected the selected pilote for my RTX3060 to be the reason of that despite the fact it is the recommanded one. However, when I change the pilote, the heat decrease.
So how I am supposed to know what driver I should use?
And does the fact I change from ubuntu to windows 11 may cause drivers issues?

Ubuntu infos:

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04

n-vidia-driver 520 does not cause excessive heat but is not the recommanded driver:
[Selected drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ChNR.png)

Comment: How are you measuring temperature?  Nvidia-settings gives the GPU temp.  sensors gives other temps.  Your choice of drivers depends upon workload.  Games may require the proprietary drivers, but run hotter. I'd use the latest nvidia 520 driver (not the -open) for your GPU. What Ubuntu release are you running, and what Nvidia drivers did you try?

Comment: @ubfan1: I dont mesure temperature but observe excessive heat while the laptop is basically not doing anything. I have updated my question. The initial selected driver was the first on the list (-open, tested). I don't understand why the preselected driver is the one causing trouble.